# Adding image to text box using officer

Tags: r, officer

I am looking at adding an image to a word document using the `officer` package. The word document template looks like this:
[image]

These are all text boxes and I am able to replace all the text such as StudentName, Enrollment number etc. but don't know how to add an image to the text box called `picture`. This is what I have tried:

```
my_doc <- read_docx('templates/form_101.docx') %>% 
  body_replace_all_text('Coursename', 'NTCC 01') %>% 
  body_replace_all_text('XXX', 'III') %>% 
  body_replace_all_text('FromDate', '26 Oct') %>% 
  body_replace_all_text('ToDate', '02 Nov 20') %>% 
  body_replace_all_text('StudentName', 'Dhiraj Khanna') %>% 
  body_replace_all_text('12345', '51511-W') %>% 
  body_replace_all_text('ABC', 'A') %>% 
  cursor_reach('picture') %>% 
  # cursor_reach('picture') %>% 
  # body_remove()
  # body_bookmark('picture') %>%
  # body_replace_img_at_bkm('picture',
  #                         value = external_img(src = 'data/images/pic1.png', 
  #                                              width = .2, height = .2))
  body_add_img(src = 'data/images/pic1.png', width = .2, height = .2,
               pos = 'on')

print(my_doc, target = 'templates/output.docx')
```

None of these approaches (including the commented out ones) give me the desired result. So how do I go about inserting an image in the text box `picture`.

The template is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-3jsr-Iqd9WVoBdROlFZUBc8QnkSLVjW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Want to put the template file somewhere we can access it? I'd see what I could do.

Comment: @BrianLang thanks, have added a link to the template file

Comment: In the template you provided, I don't find 'picture' text in the box : it seems empty.

Comment: I added 'picture' myself and gave it a try. (since it is easier to set the cursor this way). Still, it was somehow impossible for me to get this right ... got the image everywhere...just not in the text boxes xD After my tries I'd be quite curious now to know, if somebody is actually able to get this running :)  (or if it is just not supported )

Comment: Would it be a possibillity to alter the template? I think you could add a dummy image instead of the textbox and then use `body_replace_img_at_bkm`.

Comment: @AEF altering the template should be possible. This looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you alter the template. You need to

1. create a new textfield where you want the image
2. Put the image *within* the textfield, using position "in line with text"
3. Place a bookmark on the image (in my example it is called "picture")

I have uploaded a correctly altered file [here](https://gofile.io/d/AhpRt5).

You can then use the function `body_replace_img_at_bkm()` as follows:

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

my_doc <- read_docx('form_101.docx')

my_doc %>%
  body_replace_img_at_bkm("picture",
                          external_img("im02.png", width = .9, height = .9)) %>%
  print("new_form.docx")
```

Comment: looks perfect. Just one question. How do you place a bookmark on the image? Is that something to be done in Word?

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: Great! :) For future reference: The bookmatrk needs to be instered in word; click on the picture and the in the "Insert" ribbon choose "bookmark".

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try, but could't get it working (just sharing my findings here, because they would be too long for a comment and maybe they help you)

My actual conclusion was, that this probably won't work at all and is not supported by the `officer` package.

In the example you shared I added 'picture' manually, since it was in your screenshot (but missing in your word example). But even with this simplification (easier to set the cursor) it did not work.

I tried several combinations with `body_add_img`, `slip_in_img`, `body_replace_img_at_bkm`, `body_add.external_img`, `body_replace_text_at_bkm` in combination with `cursor_reach('picture')`, `cursor_forward`, `cursor_backward` calls.  (and some other rather crude efforts)

Either it did nothing or mostly it just did not put the image in the textbox.

Setting the cursor seems to work. Also adding an image in general is not a problem. Replacing a text with another text in a textbox is no problem. But adding an image to this specific textbox on the right seemed somehow impossible.

When I had the cursor in the textbox and tried to add the image there no matter what I tried, it was always either added before or after the textbox.

Comment: thanks for the try. This is exactly what I had also tried. I do have hopes on `body_replace_img_at_bkm` though

Comment: Did you have a try that came close to succeeding with 'body_replace_img_at_bkm'? Maybe this could be a starting point for another attempt from my side. All combinations I personally tried with 'body_replace_img_at_bkm' didn't look too promising. The only difference in results compared to my other tries was that sometimes the text box completely disappeared.